# In C#, how can I pick between two items?

Tags: c#, math, random

This may have been asked before, but if it has I can't find it. I'm writing a small game where sums are randomly generated for the user to answer, and correct + incorrect answers are counted. It works thus far, but I wish to implement a system where the game randomly picks between +, -, / and * symbols between the two randomly picked numbers and then, depending on which was picked, changes the way the correct answer is calculated. For a better idea, here is my current relevant code:

```
    public void makeNewSum()
    {
        var randomNum = new Random();
        num1 = randomNum.Next(0, 10);
        num2 = randomNum.Next(0, 10);
        answer = num1 + num2;
        label1.Text = num1.ToString() + " + " + num2.ToString() + " = ";
        txtAnswer.Text = "";
        txtAnswer.Focus();
```

The item 'label1' is where the sum that must be answered is displayed, though you can probably tell. What I'm trying to figure out is how I can tell it to choose between " + ", " - ", " / " and " * " where it currently always says " + ", and then change the variable 'answer' to reflect the symbol chosen. I was planning to use if statements to reflect the choice of symbol, but I'm lost for how to have it choose between them in the first place. Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an array:

```
char[] operators = { '+', '-', '*', '/' };
```

and then pick one:

```
char op = operators[randomNum.Next(operators.Length)];
```

It is possible to use something else, like `enum Operator { plus, minus, mult, ... }` instead of char. In each case you will of course need a tiny interprator to get your own correct answer from the `char` / `enum`  operator. Like:

```
switch(op)
{
   case '+' : 
      answer = a + b;
      break;

   case '-' : 
      answer = a - b;
      break;

   // etc
}
```

Comment: And so how would I start the if statements from here? As in what goes inside the brackets after 'if'? To try to be more intuitive than just asking for the straight answer, how does char work?

Comment: A `switch` seems more appropriate.

Comment: Oh, I've never heard of a switch before... But yeah, that does seem the better of the two. Thanks!

Comment: One more thing though - what does (operators.length) mean and do? And also, according to Visual Studio, System.Array doesn't contain a definition for 'length'... How can I remedy that?

Comment: Use an uppercase L, `Length`. It returns the number of items in an array.

Comment: Ah, that worked. Thanks again! What function does Length play though? What role does it serve?

Comment: The array has valid indices `0..Length-1` and we call `Random.Next(int exclusiveUpperbound)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Random r = new Random();
char[] operators = new char[] { '+', '-', '*', '/' };
char op = operators[r.Next(0, operators.Length)];
```